# Actual difference between TextView and Button

Tags: android, android-view

Considering the main purpose of a button is to react to a click event, and the fact that both `Button` and `TextView` has properties for **text, drawable (icon) and click event**, what is the actual difference between them, when should you chose one over the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the reference docs, the [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) class extends the [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) class. From there, the Button adds a few stylistic changes (e.g., default background image, additional padding) to allow quicker adaptation to your designs.

IMO, the one you choose to use should depend on how you want to design your app. If you use the default theme with minimal stylistic changes, Buttons can be quicker to visualize; on the other hand, if you are doing a lot of customization, TextView will let you do that much easier.

**Edit: ** [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/Button.java/) shows that from a functionality point of view, there is no difference aside from class name.

Comment: in newer versions button also provide elevation property too