# ConstraintLayout: z-index issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using ConstraintLayout for activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.site.path.to.AuthenticationActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log in"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/default_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

FrameLayout should hide all content of the page when visible. But it hides all content except button. Why the button doesn't hide? How to fix it?

[image: gone][image: visible]

Answer (score 8):

### Editted:

Try to set `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` to the Button/AppCompatButton

In Lollipop (Android 5.0 (API 21)) and above, Buttons have a default elevation which causes them to always draw on top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:tint="#80000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/background_image"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.049"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="There is More"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Phone"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2a98f0"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/or_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="or\nSign up with social sites"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/or_tv"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_google_plus" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarChild"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Hey, Are you sure? I remember that it worked well when i tested it.

Comment: check out my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898266/z-order-in-issue-in-constraintlayout-android

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is (*as @motis10 noted*) that Buttons have elevation by default (*post Android 5.0*), so they are drawn above other things that have no elevation.

If you give the thing you want drawn over the button a higher elevation value, then it will be drawn on top. I used: `android:elevation="40dp"` just to be safe, but I believe 8dp is the default button elevation.

Comment: That's insightful, thank you. Since Buttons have a default elevation, I changed mine to a TextView to solve the problem.  They're almost the same (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900402/actual-difference-between-textview-and-button).