# z order in issue in ConstraintLayout Android

Tags: android

I am trying to design a Signup screen using `ConstraintLayout` everything went smooth except the Z order. When the user clicks on Signup I need to show a FrameLayout on top of everything but it is not working. Please check the screenshot.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:tint="#80000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/background_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.049"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="There is More"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_first_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Phone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#2a98f0"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:text="Sign up"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/or_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="or\nSign up with social sites"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/or_tv"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_google_plus" />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarChild"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: With ProgressBar gone]
[image: With ProgressBar shown]

Answer (score 10):

Try to set `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` to the Button/AppCompatButton

In Lollipop (Android 5.0 (API 21)) and above, Buttons have a default elevation which causes them to always draw on top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:tint="#80000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/background_image"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.049"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="There is More"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Phone"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2a98f0"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/or_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="or\nSign up with social sites"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/or_tv"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_google_plus" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarChild"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: same with CardView

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to adjust `stateListAnimator` which was stated in one of the other answers.

If you need to change the z order then ensure you set the `elevation` value for the relevant components in each layer.

In this case ensure your FrameLayout's elevation has a higher value than every other component which should be behind it (I've only set the FrameLayout here but you'll need to do the rest)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarChild"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```